# Access element in event handler

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom directive which is applied to some element:

```
<table my-directive="eventName">
```

As part of the directive I emit the event:

```
scope.$emit(attr.myDirective)
```

The problem is in the event handler I need to access the element to which my directive was applied:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function() {
  $element???             
});
```

I know modifying elements is not an Angular-way but at the moment it is what I need.

Comment: Just pass the element as an argument. I don't see the problem.

Comment: what event are you emitting from the directive?

Comment: why can't you modify element within the directive?

Comment: Don't do it!!!! (I needed 4 more chars :), could you explain your general problem?

Comment: @shaunhusain I need to make a Jquery call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass element as argument:-

```
scope.$emit(attr.myDirective, $element);
```

And use it inside listener

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function(event, element) {
  //use element here           
});
```